# Dynamic content / titles / meta tags

Tags: php

I just created a new website using a tutorial as reference. My problem is mainly the title that doesn't change. But it's not possible to change anything either. Everything is static in the header defined.

I'm brand new to PHP, so any help appreciated.

This is my current code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

if (isset($_GET['content'])) {
    $content = strtolower(trim($_GET['content']));
} else {
    $content = '';
}
    include_once 'inc/header.php';

switch ($content) {
    case 'main':
    include 'inc/main.php';
    break;
    case 'blog':
    include 'inc/blog.php';
    break;
    case 'portfolio':
    include 'inc/portfolio.php';
    break;
    case 'lebenslauf':
    include 'inc/lebenslauf.php';
    break;
    case 'kontakt':
    include 'inc/kontakt.php';
    break;
    default:
    include 'inc/main.php';
}
    $content = "main";
    include_once 'inc/footer.php';
?>
```

Do you know how to edit this code to be able to change titles or meta tags dynamically or do you know a tutorial for something like a best practice include of PHP files?

Comment: My question is still unanswered.

Comment: Do I really need to repost to get the attention back?

Comment: You've got your answer from Marc and an explanation how to accomplish it from me. *Please* put some effort into solving your problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely simplest bare-bones "dynamic" header:

header.php:

```
<title><?php echo $title ?></title>
```

index.php:

```
$title = 'Hello, world!';
include('header.php');
```

Comment: This doesnt work because the title needs to be set when the header is already included.

Comment: Then you'll have to change the order of your operations. Include the sub-pages, get whatever information you need, then insert it into the header.

Comment: This is not possible with my current design.

Comment: Then you'll have to fix your design. You cannot expect PHP to be able to timetravel because you don't create/set/retrieve necessary data until AFTER that data's needed/used.

Comment: This include is only for no-js user. I already got a working AJAX script that loads my pages in. When I would include my header.php into my pages, the entire point of using ajax would be wiped out.

Comment: Do I really need to repost to get the attention back?

Comment: it not works, it shows error message "<title><br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: title in <b>C:\wamp\www\windrolinx\includes\meta.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
</title>"

Answer (score 0):

Try below Code.

```
<?php 
  $title = "";
  $description = "";
  $keywords = "";
  $url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
 if(strpos($url, 'index') !== false){
   $title = "Home | Your Site Name";
   $description = "Your Site description ";
   $keywords = "Your Site Keywords";
 }elseif(strpos($url, 'about') !== false){
   $title = "About Us";
   $description = "About description ";
   $keywords = "key words";
 }

 ?>
 <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
 <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $description; ?>" />
 <meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $keywords; ?>" />
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure of the reason why you have routed to pages like this, however i'm guessing your titles/metas are in the header.php file.

To change them you can create an array for each like this:

```
$titles = array(
   'blog.php' => 'title for blog',        
   'main.php' => 'title for main',
   //etc
);
```

In your switch, assign a variable $include or something the correct page eg:

```
case:'main':
   $include = 'main.php';
   include(main.php);
   break;
```

Then use that $include to get the title in your header.php, e.g:

```
<title><?php echo $titles[$include];?></title>
```

Comment: With your code my title is <br /> <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'> <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined variable: include in C:\wamp\www\robert richter com\inc\header.php on line <i>9</i></th></tr> <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e'...

Comment: Maybe its because I placed the array at the wrong place. Where would you place it?

Comment: That error is telling you that $include isn't set, which means you're including the header.php before you set it in your switch, include the header after setting the $include in each case of the switch, rather than before the switch.

Comment: I cant include the header.php before my current switch. I need to write it above or create a new switch. But I dont know how to do this.